# Android WebView - Intercept clicks

Tags: android, webview

I have written a simple helloworld app with a WebView which has a link to CNN on a simple.html page in my asset folder.

```
<a href="http://cnn.com">cnn.com</a>
```

How can I capture the click on this on my Activity, stop the WebView from navigating, and then inform the Activity that "http://CNN.com" was clicked?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Then you have to set a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your `WebView` and override [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`onLoadResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) methods. Let me give you a simple example:

```
WebView yourWebView; // initialize it as always...
// this is the funny part:
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);

// somewhere on your code...
WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient(){
    // you tell the webclient you want to catch when a url is about to load
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
        return true;
    }
    // here you execute an action when the URL you want is about to load
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
        if( url.equals("http://cnn.com") ){
            // do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I know this is stale but it was exactly what I was looking for EXCEPT....my navigation doesn't complete. When the user clicks a link in the WebView it goes to shouldOverrideLoading and does it's thing but doesn't complete the navigation. I do want it to complete just want to sniff what they selected first.

Comment: In that case you should not return true in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Comment: so return false then unless you really want to abort.

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate between resources requested (like CSS, JS files, images) and user-clicked links? Please take a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922547/stop-android-webview-from-trying-to-load-capture-resources-like-css-on-loaddata)