# how to POST data to android youtube application

Tags: android, webview

I'm creating video music search in android WebView and I wanted users can launch the android Youtube Application after clicked on search result in WebView.

## Example:

- Activity A Listed search result after user enter search text
- Activity B launching youtube application with search result that user clicked from Activity A.

Anyway body know how to do this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a youtube video in the default player with this

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("{url}")));
```

Replace {url} with the youtube URL

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250034/android-webview-intercept-clicks) on how to intercept click in a webview so you can call the above when certain URLs are clicked

Comment: Dear tsukimi, so, how can i post value from URL to startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("{url}"))); from WebView. Example: URL from search result are: (1)<a href="http://m.youtube.com/results?q=Result1">Result1</a> , (2)<a href="http://m.youtube.com/results?q=Result2">Result2</a> , (3)<a href="http://m.youtube.com/results?q=Result2">Result2</a>

Comment: The {url} is a URL to a you tube video, it looks like `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={id}` do you have the video Id in your list? substitute the {id} with it.