# combine file upload and connection check in webview android studio

Tags: java, android, webview, upload, connection

i want to combine 2 things in a simple Webview (android studio):

1 file upload: this took me a few days to find it for version 4.., i'm already there, file upload works!

2 - and here is the problem - i want to add a connection check, so that when there is no internet connection a message comes instead of loading default error page.
I already tried implementing the solution in this thread:
[android - how to prevent webview to load when no internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959561/android-how-to-prevent-webview-to-load-when-no-internet-connection)
and also used https://github.com/iofirag/couponsAndroidApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/oa/couponswebapp
as example...

the code i have so far: (for the file upload in my webpage)

```
package lafs.test;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


        web = new WebView(this);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsiteurl.com");
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {




            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ),
                        MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

            }

        });


        setContentView(web);


    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);


        }
    }

    //flipscreen not loading again
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



}
```

can anyone help me with this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

add the class from the example to your project,
import this class in the top of your Activity.
than use the static function that the class you added contain, **in** onCreate().

like:

```
Boolean connection = DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this);
if (connection){
    //init webView and redirect user to your upload page by the internet.
}
```