# How can I open play store market:// in webview

Tags: java, android, webview, google-play

I want to open a market:// link but it's not opening in webview. What should I do so that the link open in google play store market://

I am using cpalead ads and when someone click on install it's not opening app in playstore instead it's giving a error that market://com.example not found.

Here is code:

```
package com.packagename.weebly.free_recharge_app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class tab2 extends Fragment {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup           container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    // This next one is crazy. It's the DEFAULT location for your app's cache
    // But it didn't work for me without this line.
    // UPDATE: no hardcoded path. Thanks to Kevin Hawkins
  //  String appCachePath = this.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
  //  Log.e(TAG, "appCachePath = " + appCachePath);
   // webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



    // Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: no it's not i am trying to open in webview @MorrisonChang

Comment: Most likely you just need to capture the Google Play URI to launch to app. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250034/android-webview-intercept-clicks