# How to detect button click on webpage in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to detect button click on web page which loaded in an Android `WebView`? I am trying to display an image when particular button is clicked. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView - Intercept clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250034/android-webview-intercept-clicks)

Comment: its not working

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavascriptInterface annotation to interact with any web page in webview.

Define a method annotated with JavascriptInterface

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

```
// Instantiate the interface and set the context
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

// Show a toast from the web page
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

and add instance of this class to webview

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "AndroidInterface");
```

and call method from javascript in web page.

// this is a javascript code

```
AndroidInterface.showToast('Hello');
```